# Tx and Rx of SFH615A Issues

Tags: uart, opto-isolator, rs485

The Circuit below shows the opto-isolator circuit I implemented for my RS485 application.

[image: Opto-isolator Circuit]

RS485 Transceiver: ISL83483

Optoisolator: SFH615A

Calculated resistor Values are:
R1,R4,R6 = 4.7K.
R2,R3,R5 = 130 Ohms. ( (3.3VDC - 1.35Vf) / 15mA)

**Vnode** and **Vbus** are 3.3VDC from different Transformer Secondary Winding. **Vnode** also supplies power to the **MCU** controlling the communication flow.

For now, I am yet to connect the RS485 transceiver to the circuit, as i decided to test from the MCU to the PC using FT232 UART cable which supplies 5VDC regulated to 3.3VDC as **Vbus**.

***Now the Issue***

The MCU transmits (data to bus) and I am able to view on the PC. However, if I send a response from PC, the MCU never seems to get anything (data from bus).

To be sure, I repeated the above, but without the opto-isolator, by connecting Rx-Tx, Tx-Rx, GND-GND of MCU and PC together. And it was transmitting and receiving on both sides.

I swapped both opto-isolators, and same thing happens.

Where is the cause of this problem? Why can't the MCU get a serial message from PC via the opto-isolator.

Thanks.

**Edit**

Picture below shows the waveform obtained at PC Transmit (Cathode of R2 Diode), which seems constant each time I send it.
[image: PC Transmit]

However, this shows waveform at MCU receive (data from bus). Why is there so much distortion?
[image: MCU Receive]

**EDIT2**

I observed some communication but at different voltage levels.

**Vnode** is always **3.3V** as the **MCU** supply voltage.

My FTDI USB/232 cable is **5.0V**.

Using a **3.3V** regulator I made **Vbus** as **3.3V**, then **PC** receives from **MCU**, but **MCU** does not receive from **PC**.

If **Vbus** is 5.0 (not regulator), PC does not received from **MCU**, however a message from PC get to **MCU**.

Could there be a Voltage level issues? Can't the optoisolator work at different voltage levels at both ends? and how can I fix this?

Comment: Does your scope show good logic levels on the MCU's RX signal?

Comment: What are you doing with the "transmit/receive control" signal?

Comment: @CL for now it does not apply as the RS485 is not yet used.

Comment: What baud rate are you using? What is the allowed output current (i.e., the test condition for VOL) specified in the ISL83483 and FT232 datasheets?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have edited with the waveform.

Comment: Pullup resistors are too high, or far too much capacitance on the receive line. Measure the R-C time constant and account for why the rise time is so long. One solution is to reduce the baud rate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. We had a 0.1uf across the MCU receive line instead of 100nf (as recommended by MCU manufacturer), and the wave form was better. However MCU seems not to get it. See Edit2 for the my observation.

Comment: WHAT???? 0.1uF and 100nF are the same! (and about a factor of a thousand too high)

Comment: @BrianDrummond 0.1nf and not 100nf. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: Then update the schematic to show that cap and the mfg recommendations, and show 100pF waveforms, for 100nF is clearly wrong.